# How do I create reportable functionality that times how long a user works a case

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to create functionality (VF or JavaScript) that measures how long a user works a case. From the time they click "New" to the time they click "Save". I want to be able to view this data in a report to get an idea how long users are spending on cases on average.

Comment: I've spent the last two hours researching this and am stuck on how to approach this. I played with some JavaScript on a Visualforce page and successfully timed from when the page loaded to when it unloaded. But how to get it to time when they save the record and not just leave the page? Where to store the data in Salesforce and how to make it reportable by user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a controller extension, you can track timestamps for the initial load and the save action:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    final Long initialLoad;
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        initialLoad = Datetime.now().getTime();
        // constructor logic
    }
    public PageReference save()
    {
        Long elapsedMs = Datetime.now().getTime() - initialLoad;
        // save logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great start thank you Adrian! Where would I save the timestamps to? To the case? How would I relate them to the user who worked the case?

Comment: You haven't really provided enough context to answer these questions, but you can really save the data anywhere it makes sense. I just illustrate here how to *get* the data. It should be pretty straightforward to put it where it needs to go.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not quite sure where the data should go. So every case that gets worked would have a time stamp of when it began and when it was saved. What if it is worked by different users before it is closed? With the controller extension will it function off of the standard save button or will the button need to be overridden? Thank you for taking the time to discuss this with me.

Comment: The extension would override the standard `save` action in this case. You could save the `Datetime` values to distinct fields on `Case`, sure. It sounds like you only care about one user creating one case, no? How does the update scenario factor into it? Are you looking to timestamp each edit transaction?

Comment: The workflow sometimes involves one user creating a case and the routing it to another department for them to finish. I would need to capture the time on the case by user.

Comment: In that case, I might create a junction between `Case` and `User` called `EditSession__c` or some such. Then in addition to the relationship fields, add the two time stamps.

Comment: Would I also need to override the case close button in the controller extension? What would that look like?

Comment: Sounds like a new question! Don't forget to mark this one as solved if you have addressed the core issue. Cheers.